# JFrame + custom LayoutManeger + work with Graphisc2D (rotation)

Tags: java, swing, layout, paint, paintcomponent

I'm working on project, which uses custom Layout Manager. My goal is rotate all components by 180°. 
I have some screen which consists of JFrame. I also have some LayoutHandler, which defines some layers of layout. Each layer is instance of LayerLayout which implements LayerManager2 from java.awt 

The flow works probably like this:
I have JFrame, which represents the display. This JFrame has some default contentpane. The application set to this contentpane Layout which is represented by LayerHandler:

```
graphicalDisplayJFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new LayerLayout(layerHandler));//graphicalDisplayJFrame is JFrame which represents the display
```

The layerHandler just somehow manage the layers which are LayerLayouts which implemetns LayerLayout2 from java.awt. So it looks like layout of layouts or whatever it is. I'm not much experienced with creating custom layouts.

There I have a situation which shows creating of JFrame.

```
 graphicalDisplayJPanel = new JPanel() {
                @Override
                protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

                    super.paintComponent(g);

                    g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                    g2d.rotate(Math.PI, anchorx, anchory); //rotation 180°
                }

                  @Override
                  public void paintChildren(Graphics g) {
                       super.paintChildren(g);
                       Graphics2D g2d2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                    g2d2.rotate(Math.PI, anchorx, anchory);

                  }


            };






      graphicalDisplayJFrame = new JFrame(); //creation of JFrame

 graphicalDisplayJFrame.setContentPane(graphicalDisplayJPanel); //setting JFrame to apply rotation
```

The first part should make the rotation 180°, but it does not, even when i call repaint on graphicalDisplayJFrame. BUT when I add this:

```
JLabel hwLabel = new JLabel("Hello world.");
    hwLabel.setVisible(true);
    graphicalDisplayJFrame.add(hwLabel);
```

I cause strange thing. The JFrame and all of the components on it is accidentaly rotated by 180°. But its only static behaviour, because there are some text components on display and when there is changed the text on them its again rendered in non rotated way. 

So the question is why this could happens? 
If i divide it in two parts: 
 
a) Why the Graphics2D on JFrame does not affect the children components on its content pane. Why it only works when I add the JLabel which has no sense here but it was just experiment which caused what I wanted (= repaint with right rotation). 
 
b) I should probably somehow apply the rotation => something like overriding the paint method on each components which are added on the contentPane of JFrame. But how should can I do it? Becouse upper described layout handler just manage a bunch of layouts (layers which are probably custom layouts implementig LayoutManager2 from java.awt) and it is just feeding the components which are put on the layouts and put them on content pane. So the question should probably be where could be the place where I want to implement my custom paining which means apply the rotation (which is this part of code g2d.rotate(Math.PI, anchorx, anchory); //rotation 180°).

I hope it understandable, I made pretty bit effort to understand where could be problem and trying find out the solution, but its behave really strange. So I hope someone with more experience with this could help me out off this struggling and show me the way.

Comment: I don't think the heavy-weight components would like that very much.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the rotation at very strange points. Graphics2D.rotate() applies only to things painted *after* the rotate call, but your paint-overides rotate *after* calling super.

As for why adding a label causes rotation, hard to tell without seeing the entire code. Probably an effect of partial repaint.

You should *not modify* essentials like the graphics translation or rotation of the graphics passed to your paint methods. It has the potential to affect the parent components drawing in unexpected way and the effect can easily change depending on JRE version. Instead create a *new* graphics to pass down to your child components:

```
@Override
public void paintChildren(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    try {
        g2d.rotate(Math.PI, anchorx, anchory);
        super.paintChildren(g2d);
    } finally {
        g2d.dispose();
    }
}
```

This method leaves the original Graphics untouched, at least allowing the parent component to render normally. Rotating the graphics is still tricky and will probably have unintended side effects in the rendering process, but at least these effects are now carefully limited to the children of the rotating component.